# Windows Azure developing kind of FTP server web interface

Tags: azure, ftp

I have a site with simple file interface to get files from the server. My actual infrastructure is a VPS with IIS and a folder with lot of big files.

I'm trying to migrate the service to Window Azure, I created a Managed Web Site successfully and a VM for some other tasks.

Now the problem is with the folder with my files. I don't know how to replicate that stage on the new infraestructure.

I think to do this:

1) On my VM create and share a folder with these files

2) On my Managed Web Site, try to access to that shared folder like "\{myVM}\sharedfolder"

But, thats the way to do it? Can I share that folder internally? I need to configure an endpoint on my VM?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question a little to confirm our understanding.

“How do I store large files in Azure so that a Microsoft Azure Web Site can access them?”

Move your files to [blob storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)

Alternatively you could investigate the use of [Azure File Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) which is still in preview. [Azure Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) will enable a file share to be setup on your VM e.g. z:\Files

If you are using cloud services like web and worker roles have a read through [this article](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/using-the-azure-file-service-in-your-cloud-services-web-roles-and-worker-role/)

Comment: Yes, that is the question, but I wasn't thinking on changing my C# code, I was looking for to configure some active directory path and accessing it through the simple System.IO package. That's why I create the directory structure on the Virtual Machine. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Azure File Service, seems the solution but I'm queue to get the service :/

Comment: Usually doesn't take too long - or contact support for a "quick access token" - have fun

Comment: Beau / Santiago: Azure File Services only support Virtual Machines deployed into the same Region as the VM.  This doesn't include Websites.

Comment: Simon W you are correct but there are alternative approaches for utilizing Azure Files when using cloud services as the link above describes. Pointing out you could consider using cloud services instead of Web sites.